# Program crashes when using intrinsics

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sse, intrinsics

I'm new to using intrinsic functions, so I'm not sure why my program is crashing. I'm able to build the program, but when I run it I just get the "programname.exe has stopped working" window.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <intrin.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int N = 128;
    float x[N], y[N];
    float sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        x[i] = rand() >> 1;
        y[i] = rand() >> 1;
    }

    float* ptrx = x;
    float* ptry = y;

    __m128 x1;

    x1 = _mm_load_ps(ptrx);

    return 0;
}
```

If I comment out the 'x1 = _mm_load_ps(ptrx);' line, the program is able to run, so that is what is causing the crash.

Here is the output when building the solution...

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: intrins2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  intrins2.cpp
1>c:\...\visual studio 2013\projects\intrins2\intrins2\intrins2.cpp(20): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data
1>c:\...\visual studio 2013\projects\intrins2\intrins2\intrins2.cpp(21): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data
1>  intrins2.vcxproj -> c:\...\visual studio 2013\Projects\intrins2\Debug\intrins2.exe
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: It might be unlikely, but is it possible that the machine you execute the code on does not support the intrinsic? Note that not all processors support all intrinsics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/yc6byew8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Change `_mm_load_ps(ptrx)` to `_mm_loadu_ps(ptrx)` or compile in 64-bit mode and your program will no longer crash.

Comment: Thank you, @Zboson that worked. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `loadu` variant loads unaligned variables and makes them aligned. This alignment is required for all kinds of SSE stuff. On x64, all variables are aligned by default, so that is why it works there.

Comment: @JonB.Jones.  `_mm_load_ps` requires that the memory be 16 byte aligned.  `_mm_loadu_ps` has not such restriction.  In 64-bit mode the stack is 16 byte aligned.  However, memory from the heap is not necessarily 16 byte aligned.  On older CPUs `_mm_loadu_ps` was much slower than `_mm_load_ps` even on aligned memory but that's not longer the case.  Just use `_mm_loadu_ps` and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your "source" (the array `x`) is not aligned to the size that the SSE instructions require.

You can fix this with using the "unaligned" load instruction, or you can fix it by using the [`__declspec(align(n))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx), e.g:

```
    float __declspec(align(16)) x[N];
    float __declspec(align(16)) y[N];
```

Now your `x` and `y` arrays are aligned to 16 bytes, and are viable for access [on indices that are multiples of 4, of course] from SSE instructions. Note that unaligned access is not allowed for general SSE instructions that take memory arguments, so for example a `_mm_max_ps` requires that the second argument (in Intel order, first in AT&T order) is an aligned memory location.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful, but I don't really understand what it means to be aligned or unaligned..

Comment: @JonB.Jones, aligned means that the memory address is a multiple of 16.  You can test this do.  Do `printf("%p %d\n", ptrx, ptrx%16)` and you will see that the address is not a multiple of 16 bytes (in 32-bit mode).  If you compile in 64-bit mode or use `__declspec(align(16))` it will be a multiple of 16 bytes, i.e. aligned to 16 bytes.

Comment: Oh, wow, okay. That clears a lot of this up for me. I forgot that the length of memory addresses in Intel processors are not necessarily fixed, as in MIPS processors. Man, now I regret not coming here sooner haha. Thanks so much for your help, guys.

Comment: What about dynamically allocated memory?